# Is a single string value considered valid JSON?

Tags: json

Do you consider the JSON web response:

```
"A serialization error occurred"
```

to be valid or not?

[Some validators accept it](http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html) while others don't.

Comment: What response are you talking about? Could you possibly share that?

Comment: I was refering the the single string value: "A serialization error occurred"

Comment: Make sure your string is escaped with quotes (""), i.e. its not just 
`A serialization error occurred`
but
`"A serialization error occurred"`

Answer (score 40):

As for new [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt), json, containing only single value is pretty valid.

> A JSON text is a serialized value.  Note that certain previous specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an array.

Comment: Yes, it is valid. Note that for better interoperability you can return a single element array: 
`[ "value" ]`

Comment: For reasons of extensibility, one should always use an object, especially when dealing with a Rest API.

Answer (score 30):

There's a change of heart on this between [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) and [RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159):

**RFC4627**:

> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.
>
> ```
>   JSON-text = object / array
> ```

**RFC7159**:

> A JSON text is a serialized value.  Note that certain previous
> specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an
> array.  Implementations that generate only objects or arrays where a
> JSON text is called for will be interoperable in the sense that all
> implementations will accept these as conforming JSON texts.
>
> ```
>   JSON-text = ws value ws
> ```

No philosophical or practical justification is provided for this change of heart. The earlier version probably makes more sense as it consistently dictates that both a singe list element and a single map element (a pair or tuple) be contained. The second version allows only a single list element to be uncontained.

Answer (score 19):

According to the grammar exposed in http://www.json.org/ (which references the [Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition - December 1999](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) par.5.1.5 The JSON Grammar) it's wrong:

The initial element must be:

[image]

[image]

and then a value can be a string:

[image]

Comment: Hi Tony, 

I did consult that page too, and I had the same understanding. But I wanted to ask the community since some sites (like the one I putted as reference) consider the single string value as a valid json response. Seeing the responses here just confirm that is does not make sense.

Comment: I tried that site and I agree with you it seems misleading. Usually I use http://jsonlint.com/ which is not accepting a string as a valid JSON: 

"Parse error on line 1:
"ciao"
^
Expecting '{', '[' "  . The error message is clear: it is expecting  an Object or an Array.

Answer (score 1):

From [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> ```
> A JSON text is a serialized object or array.
>     JSON-text = object / array
> ```

IE, the root element has to be an object or array, and can't be a string value by itself.

Answer (score -4):

I don't care if some validator accepts it. It's wrong. It's a question of good practice, Json format must be `{"key": "value", .....}`. If you consider that text Json, can work, but for the rest of programmer it's not a serious Json. If you use only that text, then you don't need Json.

Comment: Not that simple. New specifications consider single values as valid JSON.

Comment: Consider the case of an JSON API, a very common case. When returning a 404 or other error how should the value be encoded in your world? I would also suggest that "serious Json" (surely you mean "serious JSON"?) is what the JSON spec defines. For the internet and the content type application/json that is RFC-7159 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159) and it allows for a pure string, specifically: "JSON-text = ws value ws [...] A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of the following three literal names: false null true".