# Mapping from solitary JSON value to class in RestKit

Tags: objective-c, json, rest, restkit

I am contacting a REST service that does not always conform to KVC with RestKit. The response I'm having trouble with is simple:

```
true
```

I do not need this value mapped to a class, but this is the class I have set up to receive this value:

```
@interface BooleanResponse : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) BOOL response;
@end
```

I have already [handled top-level arrays](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#mapping-without-kvc), so I attempted the same mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[BooleanResponse class]];
[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"response"]];
```

Upon completion, RestKit prints the error: `Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json'`

Interestingly, JSONLint says that `true` is invalid JSON--but a single boolean response makes sense for this request. (Aside from it being an unnamed value, although as I mentioned KVC is not followed.)

I did not implement the service. Can I make RestKit handle solitary values, or am I stuck handling them as special cases?

Comment: I guess you have a suitable response descriptor. Does the trace log give more information?

Comment: It seems to agree with JSONLint that a single value isn't valid JSON. http://pastebin.com/ZMFNMjbz

Comment: Re: validity, I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13318420/382780) that firmly answers that `true` is *NOT* valid JSON. I'm still interested if there's a way to get around this with RestKit, although I'm going to try to get the service changed.

Comment: What request are you sending, should you really be using AFNetworking?

Comment: I am contacting a RESTful service with a request for JSON data. This example is a simple ping GET request, although there will be more complex queries in the future. I'm not familiar with the differences between RestKit and AFNetworking (although I think that RestKit is built on AFNetworking). I think that the object mapping will be useful in this project, though, assuming AFNetworking lacks that.

Comment: You have the difference right, but you can use both in the same project where each is most suitable.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping to avoid special cases, but if the service can't be changed that sounds like a good solution. (Especially considering I already have AFNetworking in my RestKit build!)