# IOS/Objective-C/JSON:Obtain single value from Web Service in JSON

Tags: ios, json

I want to obtain a single value from a web service in JSON, just a file name i.e. `"picture.png";` based on some parameters passed.

Can IOS (I guess `NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:)` handle this single value in JSON or on the server side should I have it send a dictionary key as in `{"pic": "picture.gif"}`

If there is no picture, I am returning "nopic" so again should I have it return `"error"` or `{"error": "nopic"}`

I gather the various JSON specifications are [conflicting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318420/json-standard-a-single-string-value) on this point so my interest is just practical...how best to handle this case.

Thanks for any guidance on this

Comment: It is safier to send dict since it will be valid json.

Comment: if you use like this `{"key": "error"}` and `{"key": "pic.jpe"}` it is east way to use