# Minimal JSON data structure containing a value

Tags: json

Looking at [json spec](http://www.json.org/), I'm not sure whether a `value` is permitted to stand alone, or is only permitted as part of `object` or `array` structure.

This is valid JSON:

```
[123]
```

But is this valid JSON:

```
123
```

Comment: Just try `JSON.parse(123)` in the console.

Comment: @torazaburo I tried several online parsers and validators, and about half of them said it was not valid JSON. They are presumably using prominent libraries for server side languages, yet they differ. I would be not at all surprised if different browsers gave different answer in their console. Hence my asking about the *spec*.

Comment: Which online validator(s)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318420/is-a-single-string-value-considered-valid-json.

Comment: @torazaburo e.g. http://json.parser.online.fr/ https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [ECMA-404, The JSON Data Interchange Standard (pdf)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), which is linked from the JSON.org page you linked:

> A JSON text is a sequence of tokens formed from Unicode code points that conforms to the JSON value grammar.

And:

> A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or null.

As such, the value `123` is valid JSON, representing an integer.

Comment: `... that conforms to the JSON value grammar.` - that is precisely the important bit that was wondering about, thanks!

Comment: I didn't realize that "ECMA-404, The..." is actually a link! :)) Usability failure: visited links are colored BROWN!

Answer (score 0):

A value is permitted to stand alone.

The rule has been changed a few years ago.

Comment: You'd have to show me an outdated reference with the "old rule" to convince me it was ever otherwise. In the many years I've been working with JSON, it has always allowed for values to stand alone (outside of an object or array).

Comment: _(not that you're required to convince me ;) )_

Comment: @JAAulde Please look at [rfc4627](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627). It's also mentioned in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I believe it is pretty ambiguous. I'd say latter documents are clarification as opposed to change. I could very well be wrong, though. Cheers!