# Converting int output to JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, formatting

I have created an ASP.NET Web API which finds the sum of two integers using an addition function from a dll file. When i run the application (`http://localhost:52241/api/dlladdition/9/6`) i get results as `"15"`. The result i want is something like `{ "result" : 15}` (JSON format). How do i achieve that? The JSON codes that i have included in my codes does not seem to work.

**Here are my codes:**

**Addition.cs**

```
using ClassLibraryDll;
public class Addition
{
    static int num1;
    static int num2;
    int sum = MathClass.Add(num1, num2);
}
```

**DllAdditionController.cs**

```
public class Temp
{
    public int num1 { get; set; }
    public int num2 { get; set; }
    public int sum { get; set; }
}

public class DllAdditionController : ApiController
{
    private Addition addition = new Addition();

    public int GET(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int result = ClassLibraryDll.MathClass.Add(num1, num2);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        return (json);
    }
}
```

Someone please help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Please show the code which is making a call to the API

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get ASP.NET Web API to return JSON instead of XML using Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome)

Comment: This whole application is the API that i am creating. It calls a dll file (using `ClassLibraryDll` i have referenced the dll file)

Comment: Are you trying to run http://localhost:52241/api/dlladdition/9/6 using a Web browser?

Comment: yeS i am trying to run that using a web browser

Comment: `{15}` this is not a valid JSON, valid JSON object always has pairs of key (property quoted by "") and value. If you want some valid JSON object in this case, it should be `{ "result" : 15}` or simply `15`.

Comment: @KingKing I want to get `{ "result" : 15}`

Comment: How do i get that result?

Comment: that format requires an object, you can declare a class having one property of `result` (whose data Type is `int`). Well it's a bit more code to write. Your `GET` method of course should return that type, not `int`.

Comment: You're trying to complicate things, the simple return value of `15` should be totally fine in this case.

Comment: @KingKing my  project manager insists for it to be in JSON format :/

Comment: unless you design your own of JSON result format with complex object. The simple value `15` is also a valid JSON-parsable string, meaning deserializing `"15"` would return the number 15.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the response to by JSON by using the JSON Media-Type Formatter

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
```

If you like to restrict your Web API response to either JSON or XML only, you can call this from your Application_Start method, defined in Global.asax.

```
void ConfigureApi(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Remove the JSON formatter
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);

    // or

   // Remove the XML formatter
   config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
}
```

You may refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#removing-the-json-or-xml-formatter for more information.

Comment: Where do i put `var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;` this set of codes?

Comment: Hi, can put it inside Global.asax.cs file, inside the Application_Start(). Or if you are using any other startup class, just add the line of codes in.

Answer (score 1):

> my project manager insists for it to be in JSON format :/

It [**is** valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13318420/87698). Your project manager needs to read up on the current JSON specs.

If you want your result wrapped in an object with a `result` property, you are free to define a class with a single property `result` and return this class instead.

Comment: How do i do that. Please guide me more if u could

Comment: @SusmithaNaidu: Where exactly do you need help? Do you know how to declare a C# class with a property?

Comment: I am not sure. I did the addition.cs class. I have to add in more codes there?

Comment: @SusmithaNaidu: Do you understand what I mean when I say "declare a new C# class with a single property"? If not, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: No i do not understand :(

Comment: @SusmithaNaidu: Do you know what a class is? Do you know what a property is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158667/discussion-between-susmitha-naidu-and-heinzi).