# Gson conversion of a simple string fails with exception

Tags: java, gson

I need to convert a json string to particular type based on the function's return type. The json string could also be a plain string. I am facing issues while converting the strings using gson.fromJson method.

Why is an exception thrown in gson.fromJson if the string contains a space? And how do I get around this?

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

class Trial {
    Object retu() {
        return "BEVERLY OUTLAW";
    }
}

public class sample {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Trial obj = new Trial();

        Method func = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()[0];
        Object o = gson.fromJson("beverlyoutlaw", func.getGenericReturnType());
        System.out.println(o); ---> this prints beverlyoutlaw
        o = gson.fromJson("beverly outlaw", func.getGenericReturnType()); ---> This throws an exception!
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is pretty simple: it's questionable wether a single string is valid Json or not, since two different RFCs specifying Json differ on this (more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318420/is-a-single-string-value-considered-valid-json ). Gson does not consider a string valid Json and needs the outermost element to be either an object or an array.

Comment: why does it work on Strings without spaces then?

Comment: I have to admit, I missed that part. Have you tried `gson.fromJson("\"beverly outlaw\"", ...)`? I'm pretty sure strings in Json need to be enclosed by quotes, even without spaces, so it's already "best effort" to even parse strings without them at all.

Comment: Yes that works!

Comment: You're kind of going out of your way here to try to break things: The non JSON string passed to `fromJson`, the target type retrieved through `getGenericReturnType`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to store and retrieve function outputs as a json. While retrieving I convert the output based on the return type of the function. This is part of the use case. Since a quoted string is a valid json [atleast jsonlint doesn't complain], I stored as a simple string, but ran into the issue I pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Json need to be surrounden by quotes. That is - in the Json itself!

Neither `"beverlyoutlaw"` nor `"beverly outlaw"` contain quotes in the string - the quotes are just part of the Java String literal.

Apparently Gson does not enforce this for strings without spaces - for strings with spaces however it is strictly necessary.

To fix your issue, use `o = gson.fromJson("\"beverly outlaw\"", func.getGenericReturnType());`

Comment: This is not quite right _for strings with spaces however it is strictly necessary_. The exception is thrown because Gson hasn't consumed the full input string, not because what it considered a string contained a space.

Comment: You're correct, @SotiriosDelimanolis. However in the end it means the same thing, just put the other way around: if Gson has not consumed the entire input when it stops parsing the string, but your entire json is a single string with a space, then quotes are needed in order for Gson to parse your Json entirely as that exact single string.